# sbt-play-soap 1.1.3 not found

Tags: scala, soap, playframework, sbt

I have a Play! 2.6 project with scala 2.12 and sbt 1.1.6

I need to perform SOAP api call in my service so I saw Play! have something called **[Reactive SOAP for Play](https://github.com/playframework/play-soap#installation)**, and when I went in the documentation (https://github.com/playframework/play-soap#installation) the first stage was to add the plugin:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("play-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-soap" % "1.1.3")
```

but I get an error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-soap;1.1.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-soap:1.1.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
```

did someone tried this ever? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version `1.1.3` is only available for `sbt 0.13`.

Since you are using `sbt 1.x.x`, you have to use version `1.1.4`

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("play-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-soap" % "1.1.4")
```